# Jump to narrowed subtree

Tags: org-mode

I would like to quickly access my org-contacts stored in the file ~/org/contacts.org through rofi.

```
egrep "^\* " ~/org/contacts.org |rofi -dmenu -i
```

allows me to select the contact through rofi. However, I fail to forward the selection to emacs:

```
emacsclient --eval "(org-narrow-to-subtree $(egrep "^\* " ~/org/contacts.org |rofi -dmenu -i))" ~/org/contacts.org
```

What I want to do is: start emacsclient, then open the contacts.org file and narrow the subtree to the selection I made in rofi. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Do you only want to initiate this from the command line, or might you want to start from already being in emacs?